# Injected timeout not working

Tags: angularjs

I was just trying a simple timeout service, cannot still figure out what's missing:-

```
    $timeout($scope.checkLogin("s" , "s"), 4000);
```

And here's the function:-

```
    $scope.checkLogin = function(user, role) {
    console.log("user: " + user);
    if (user == "-99") {
        $scope.errorMessage = "Wrong user/password";
        $rootScope.notLogin = false;
    } else {
        $rootScope.username = user;
        $rootScope.userrole = role;
        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $rootScope.notLogin = true;
        $location.path("/home");
    }
};
```

Here's my controller's header:-

```
    App.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http, $location,
    $rootScope, $window, $timeout, loginService)
```

Its getting immediately called, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$timeout` accepts callback function. There is no way how the evaluation of    `$scope.checkLogin("s" , "s")` can be delayed in:

```
$timeout($scope.checkLogin("s" , "s"), 4000);
```

It should be:

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.checkLogin("s" , "s"); }, 4000);
```